# Counting all occurrences of a string within all files in a folder

Tags: linux, grep

How do I count all occurrences of a particular string in all files in a folder?

For example,

1.txt: 'hahaha hehe'
2.txt: 'ha hee'

I would like to count all occurrences of 'ha' in these files.

I tried:

```
grep "ha" * | wc-l
```

But it just gives me individual occurrences in file output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close. To get a total count of all occurrences of "ha" within all .txt files in a folder:

```
grep -o "ha" *.txt | wc -l
```

From `man grep`:

```
-o, --only-matching
       Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with
       each such part on a separate output line.
```

This works because  *each* match is printed on a separate line, thus allowing `wc -l` to count all of them.

By default, however, grep only finds the first occurrence on a line and outputs the whole line. Likewise, option `-c` only finds the first occurrence in all lines, then outputs how many lines had 1 (or more) matches.

**EDIT:**

Here is a way to print the total number of occurrences within each individual file (with filenames):

```
find *.txt -printf 'echo "$(grep -o "ha" %p | wc -l) %p";' | sh

#Example output
3 file1.txt
1 file2.txt
```

**Explanation:**

`find *.txt` - finds .txt files

`-printf` - prints everything between the single-quotes (formatted) to standard output, replacing occurrences of `%p` with find's output (file names)

`$(grep -o "ha" %p | wc -l)` - works as above

`| sh` - the output from `-printf` (which are commands) are piped to a shell and executed

Note that printf is invoked once per filename.

Comment: How about if I want to find out number of occurrences in each individual file

Comment: Guys, is there some reason for why you cannot use the features of grep? grep -H -c ip6 * seems to me what's requested

Comment: @GombaiSándor: `-H` prints the filenames but the `-c` option still only finds one match per line. OP wants all

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `grep`, try use `ag -c ha` [SilverSearcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher):

```
1.txt:3
2.txt:1
```

It is more faster! If you are using ubuntu, you can install package `silversearcher-ag`.